# Expand even tr tags in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table formatted data like below in screenshot.

[image]
And I need show all `tr` tags which have `ChildBundle` class on click of `ExpandAll` button

Here is the jQuery code I'm using to perform action.

```
$(document).on('click', '#ExpandAll', function () {
    $('#view_job_tbl > tbody > tr').each(function () {

        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        var number = parseFloat(className.match(/-*[0-9]+/));
        if ($('.ChildBundle' + number + ':visible').length)
            $('.ChildBundle' + number).hide();
        else
            $('.ChildBundle' + number).show();

    });
});
```

But this is not working. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I think its not possible to expand tr and you must expand td

Comment: There is no other way to do it ? :(

Comment: @WaldemarIce that is not true

Comment: Get rid of the number in the class name. Classes should be common name for common use. Use ID to create unique identifiers or store data in data attributes

Comment: @charlietfl : you meant do i need to create `class name` without number ?

Comment: I am saying there is no good reason to create it with the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#view_job_tbl > tbody > tr[class*=ChildBundle]').each(function () {



        $(this).toggle();

});
```

Comment: syntax problem with mismatched quotes

Comment: Yes sorry, i have removed the '.

Comment: FYI- also don't need the `each`..can use `toggle()` on whole collection

Comment: Yes i know, but with the .each is more clear to understand for Pankaj.